# Unity 3D: Adding rigidbody to sphere crashes frame rate

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a strange issue happening in Unity 3D: I have an empty scene, then I add new sphere game object, press run, the ball stays stationary. I can see in the Game window that FPS are ok.

Then I add Rigidbody component to the same sphere and press play. The sphere starts to fall down as it should, but the frame rate drops dramatically, that is below 3 FPS.

I've updated the Nvida drivers, I also tried this in both 32 and 64 bit newest Unity versions.

It seems that there something wrong with the physics calculations. 
Does anyone experienced similar issues?
Any tips on how could I debug this issue further?

Comment: in my unity its fine. 5.4 here i have the same fps on both cases and are near 80.

Comment: That's really weird behaviour - if you open the Unity Profiler, it might give you a little more insight into what exactly is causing the drop in performance. Run it before and after you add the Rigidbody, and see what the graphs tell you.

Comment: Is it possible that your scene is full of other rigidbodies that aren't set to kinematic? it's possible that since you've introduced a moving object, it has to check all the other rigid bodies in your scene for collisions. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Some times Vsync can act as the FPS dropper.

so check Edit>>Project Settings>>Quality>>V Sync Count

Set V Sync Count it to **Don't Sync**.
it should increase your FPS.

if it does not help than you might have some script that is acting as weird.
so try Profiler .Go to Windows>>Profiler .

and run your game see what is taking your highest CPU.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice, but unfortunately changing the V Sync didn't help. I used a profiler and find out that the allocated memory is getting filled linearly http://imgur.com/a/zOv9U. I disabled all the scripts and that didn't change anything. Here is also a screen from CPU part: http://imgur.com/a/1YYWq. Running the scene without rigidbody component attached to the sphere results in ~900 FPS.

Comment: @Jacob S do you have any Scripts Or Plugin in your project. Because 3000+ physics.processing calls is too much. Which version of unity you use.